# Can I open multiple maps/urls in different panels within the same page?

Tags: html

I'm relatively new to HTML and I don't really know how to phrase this question. But I'm looking for a way to open multiple maps onto a single page that all changed based on each other's inputs

**Example:**
I want to open https://www.google.com/maps/@40.754912,-73.9834648,15.79z on the left and https://www.google.com/maps/@40.754912,-73.9834648,3926m/data=!3m1!1e3 on the right. One would show the plain map while the other would show the satellite. But, as I move around the left plain map, it would automatically update the URL/HTML for the second panel (or vice versa) to move to the appropriate lat-long.

Ideally I'd want 4 panels that all work off each other, but for example's sake I want to start with 2.

I don't really know if this is even possible, but I thought I'd ask you guys before pouring countless hours into something that's impossible.

Thanks

Ideally what I'm looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUvmz.jpg

Comment: `But, as I move around the left plain map, it would automatically update the URL/HTML for the second panel (or vice versa) to move to the appropriate lat-long.` Bad idea, as it would refresh the page every time you update its URL. Maybe you would have more luck using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation).

Comment: I looked into the Google Maps API, however I want to use a subscription based website called OnXMaps for 2-3 of the panels (Topographic, Hybrid, and/or Satellite) because it gives additional information (trails, vegetation, historic wildfires, public/private land, etc.). If I didn't need to use this site, I would 100% use Google Maps API, but I'm kinda locked in.